# Ember.js with js objects

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I want an Ember view to hold a Javascript object. Something like:

```
 var foo = function(){
   function bar(){
     alert("Hi");
   };
 };

 MyApp.MyView = Ember.View.extend({
   boo: new foo();
 });

 MyApp.MyView.boo.bar();
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm no really sure what your question or problem is. Perhaps you could phrase it in the form of a question.

A few tips though.

1. You should be careful about creating reference type values within a class definition because all instances of that class will share the same reference. In your example, every instance of MyApp.MyView will share the same boo object.
2. In your example, you haven't yet created a view, just build a view class. Doing: `MyApp.myView = MyApp.MyView.create().append()` should build you a view and insert it into the DOM.
3. When reference values deep in an object chain it's handy to use Ember's `getPath`/`setPath` because they bring a level of safety. Example:

```js
if(typeof MyApp.getPath('MyView.boo.bar') === 'function') {
    MyApp.getPath('MyView.boo').bar();
}
```